# Comparing discriminated union cases with < and > in F#

Tags: f#, comparison-operators, discriminated-union

I'm learning F# and I am building a quick set of functions which compare two poker hands and determine the winner.

I made this discriminated union to represent categories of poker hands:

```
type Category =
    | HighCard
    | OnePair
    | TwoPair
    | ThreeOfAKind
    | Straight
    | Flush
    | FullHouse
    | FourOfAKind
    | StraightFlush
```

I use this code to compare categories to determine if one hand is better than another:

```
if playerCategory > houseCategory then Win
elif playerCategory < houseCategory then Loss
// ... More code to handle cases within the same category
```

So, for example, the expression:

```
let playerCategory = FullHouse
let houseCategory = HighCard
if playerCategory > houseCategory then Win
elif playerCategory < houseCategory then Loss
// ... Other code
```

Would have the value `Win`.

However, I don't understand how the < and > operators are able to work here.  (Originally I had a function which mapped each case to a numeric value, but I realized it wasn't necessary.)  If I rearrange the order of the cases then the logic breaks, so I'm assuming each case is assigned some default value corresponding to its order within the type?

But I would definitely appreciate a bit more insight...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is described in the specification:

> by default, record, union, and struct type definitions called
>   structural types implicitly include compiler-generated declarations 
>   for structural equality, hashing, and comparison. These implicit
>   declarations consist of the following  for structural equality and
>   hashing

**8.15.4 Behavior of the Generated CompareTo implementations**

> If T is a union type, invoke Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Operators.compare
>   first on the index of the union cases for the two values, and then on
>   each corresponding field pair of x and y for the data carried by the
>   union case. Return the first non-zero result.

Comment: So when it says "the index of the union cases for the two values", "index" is referring to a case's position within the union type?

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what Lee said, there's also in the spec

**8.5.4 Compiled Form of Union Types for Use from Other CLI Languages**

> A compiled union type U has:

...

> One CLI instance property *U.Tag* for each case C. This property fetches or computes an integer tag corresponding to the case.

The compiler-generated `CompareTo` method uses the backing fields of these properties to determine the index as stipulated in *8.15.4*. This is evidenced by IlSpy:

```
int tag = this._tag;
int tag2 = category._tag;
if (tag != tag2)
{
    return tag - tag2;
}
if (this.Tag != 0)
{
    return 0;
}
```